# How do I output time for california?

Tags: c#, datetime

How can I output the current time in California from my website?

I want visitors to know the current time for my application.

Answer (score 2):

```
TimeZoneInfo pacificZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time");
DateTime pacificTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, pacificZone);
```

The advantage of this is that it doesn't depend on what time zone the server is currently set to.

Comment: Isn't there a way that returns a DateTimeOffset? That would be nicer IMO. My solution (deleted)  doesn't work :-(

Comment: @dtb, why do we need to explicitly get the offset?  He said he wants to output the actual time.

Comment: System.TimeZoneNotFoundException. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908343/list-of-timezone-ids-for-use-with-findtimezonebyid-in-c

Answer (score 1):

Is your server located in California? If so, then `DateTime.Now` will return the current time in the current timezone.

If not, you can either hard-code the offset from UTC of California and use `DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(offset)` or you can use a database such as the [tz database](http://www.twinsun.com/tz/tz-link.htm) which will help with things like automatically adjusting for daylight savings and so on.

There is also the [TimeZoneInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx) class, introduced in .NET 3.5 that lets you enumerate the timezone information installed into windows. You should be able to calculate it from that as well.