# How to convert a datetime to specific timezone in c#?

Tags: c#

I need help converting a `DateTime` to a specific time zone. What I have below is not working correctly.

`gmTime` = `03/02/2013 1:00:00 AM`

```
 TimeZoneInfo timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
 var time = timeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(gmTime, timeZone);
```

When I debug the value of `time`, which should be `03/01/2013 8:00:00 PM` when the zone is applied, it comes back as `03/02/2013 1:00:00 AM`.

If I do `time.ToLocalTime()` then I get the correct value. However, I need to convert `time` to different time zones.

Comment: Have you considered using Noda time instead? https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/

Comment: I was going to suggest noda-time as well, I've also used http://www.babiej.demon.nl/Tz4Net/main.htm with success

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert DateTime in Specific timezone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869051/how-to-convert-datetime-in-specific-timezone)

Answer (score 21):

DateTime objects have a "Kind" variable which helps TimeZoneInfo know how to treat it. In the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382835.aspx) for TimeZone.ConvertTime it has the following:

> DateTimeKind.Local, Converts the local time to the time in destinationTimeZone.
>
> DateTimeKind.Utc, Converts Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) to the time in destinationTimeZone.
>
> DateTimeKind.Unspecified, Assumed to be Local.

For example:

```
  Console.WriteLine("Local time zone is '{0}'.", TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id);

  var gmTime          = new DateTime(2013, 03, 02, 01, 00, 00, DateTimeKind.Utc);
  var localTime       = new DateTime(2013, 03, 02, 01, 00, 00, DateTimeKind.Local);
  var unspecifiedTime = new DateTime(2013, 03, 02, 01, 00, 00);

  var timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");

  var gmTimeConverted           = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(gmTime,          timeZone); // 03/02/2013 8:00:00AM
  var localTimeConverted        = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(localTime,       timeZone); // 03/02/2013 
  var unspecifiedTimeConverted  = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(unspecifiedTime, timeZone);

  Console.WriteLine("Converting GMT         to EST: {0}", gmTimeConverted);
  Console.WriteLine("Converting Local       to EST: {0}", localTimeConverted);
  Console.WriteLine("Converting Unspecified to EST: {0}", unspecifiedTimeConverted);
```

Results in:

```
Local time zone is 'Pacific Standard Time'.
Converting GMT         to EST: 3/1/2013 8:00:00 PM
Converting Local       to EST: 3/2/2013 4:00:00 AM
Converting Unspecified to EST: 3/2/2013 4:00:00 AM
```

Or if your local timezone is 'Eastern Standard Time' you get these results

```
Local time zone is 'Eastern Standard Time'.
Converting GMT         to EST: 3/1/2013 8:00:00 PM
Converting Local       to EST: 3/2/2013 1:00:00 AM
Converting Unspecified to EST: 3/2/2013 1:00:00 AM
```

If you'd like TimeZoneInfo to treat 'Unspecified' like Utc, you should function like TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc. Again from [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.converttimefromutc.aspx)

> DateTimeKind.Local, Throws an ArgumentException.
>
> DateTimeKind.Unspecified or DateTimeKind.Utc, Converts from Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

Answer (score 8):

Try something like the following Chace

```
TimeZoneInfo estTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
DateTime estDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(timeUtc, estTimeZone);
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code will let you go from any arbitrary time zone to any other.  We make use of [DateTimeOffset](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4331189/1467396) which will allow you to pass the UTC Offset in.  You may consider whether just using `DateTimeOffset` instead of `DateTime` will suit your needs. But if you want to use `DateTime` instead, here is some code that will do the conversion for you:

```
public DateTime ChangeTimeZone(DateTime dateTimeInput, TimeZoneInfo sourceTimeZone, TimeZoneInfo destTimeZone)
{
    var zonedTime = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.SpecifyKind(dateTimeInput, DateTimeKind.Unspecified),
                                       sourceTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(dateTimeInput));
    var utcTime = zonedTime.UtcDateTime;
    
    return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(utcTime, destTimeZone);
}
```

You may notice that we explicitly call `SpecifyKind` and set it to `Unspecified`.  The reason for this is because if the `Kind` is specified on the `dateTimeInput` then the UtcOffset must match that `Kind` -- so if it is DateTimeKind.Utc, then that number must be 0. If it is Local, then it must be whatever the local time offset is or you will get an exception.  Of course, if you already know the `Kind` then you could skip this function and just go straight to `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime`.