# Converting a dateTime to a specific timezone

Tags: c#

The results that I get back are in UTC and I need this to be in my current timezone.

```
var accidentDetail = db.sp_InsertAccidentRegister(Convert.ToDateTime(GetFieldValue(accidentReportDetail.fields, "Date/Time of Accident"))
```

I'm new to coding, especially in C# so any recommendations/suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: [DateTime.ToLocalTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tolocaltime?view=net-6.0)

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15169679/how-to-convert-a-datetime-to-specific-timezone-in-c) might contain the answer you need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a datetime to specific timezone in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15169679/how-to-convert-a-datetime-to-specific-timezone-in-c)