# C# DateTime.Now.ToString (EST)

Tags: c#, datetime

My app is connected to a database and it captures the time which is displayed within application.

All records have time of creation and date/time should be in EST because our users are working in different timezones.

My question: how to display `DateTime.Now` in EST timezone rather than using system or UTC time?

Current code:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label2date_.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM dd yy HH:mm");
}
```

Comment: There are plenty of questions talking about converting time to different TZ like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15169679/how-to-convert-a-datetime-to-specific-timezone-in-c... Clearly you are asking for something else since you likely already seen all those questions. Could you please [edit] the question to explain why converting DateTime to DateTime in another timezone first and then formatting did not work and what exact output you want to see (i.e. where you want TZ to be shown, if ever)

Comment: If it is only important to show EST on the front end, just format whatever the backend gives you in that time zone. It basically doesn't matter what timezone value goes in the DB, as long as you use the DateTimeOffset type. It's trivial to take any arbitrary DateTimeOffset on the front end and do the formatting there to any desired output.

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation**

You can use the built-in *TimeZoneInfo* module to get the current local timezone information, and use *TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime* do the conversion from one timezone to another.

**Code**

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    
        DateTime dtNow = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();
        // Define the time zone for your local time
        TimeZoneInfo localtz = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
        // Define the Eastern Standard Time (EST) zone
        TimeZoneInfo esttz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
        // Convert local time to EST
        DateTime dtEST = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dtNow, localtz, esttz);
    
        Console.WriteLine("Local Time: " + dtNow.ToString("MM dd yy HH:mm"));
        Console.WriteLine("EST Time: " + dtEST.ToString("MM dd yy HH:mm"));
    
        label2date_.Text = dtEST.ToString("MM dd yy HH:mm");
    }
```

Comment: Great, it works now.
Thank you, you're the best.

Comment: HI @RemakerShadow, Please accept my answer, if it works well

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display local time to the user in a web app **and be able to support multiple timezones** it may be best to use utc timestamps in the back-end code and make the client code (~javascript) make the translations.

---

MS Learn has a section for translating time in the [Converting times between time zones](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/converting-between-
time-zones#converting-utc-to-a-designated-time-zone) article.

For example:

```
DateTime utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow; // UTC, not local machine time

var tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time"); // or Eastern etc.
DateTime cstNow = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcNow, tz);

Console.WriteLine($"Utc: {utcNow}");
Console.WriteLine($"CST: {cstNow}");
```

produces:

```
Utc: 5/10/2023 2:49:19 AM
CST: 4/10/2023 9:49:19 PM
```

Again, please note that this will not work well if the users use multiple timezones.