# Convert UTC to specific time zone

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have dates stored in my database as UTC. I'd like to convert them to CST (Central Standard Time).

I've looked everywhere and I've only found ways to convert UTC time to local time. How can I convert it to a specific time zone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc` from .NET 3.5/4.0?

Answer (score 3):

Try this way

```
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(DateTime.Now, "New Zealand Standard Time", "UTC")
```

More  discussions :

[How to convert DateTime in Specific timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869051/how-to-convert-datetime-in-specific-timezone)

http://blog.mozilla.org/it/2012/11/16/converting-timezone-specific-times-in-mysql/