# Convert date time to format "dd.MM.yyyy" from another time zone to +2

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I want to convert this format:

```
2012-08-09T07:48:16+02:00

2012-01-17T17:49:05+01:00

2012-01-17T17:49:05-05:00
```

to "`dd.MM.yyyy`" in time zone **UTC+02:00**

Comment: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=593 follow this link to convert your time zone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this way:

```
    var dt = DateTime.Parse("2012-08-09T07:48:16+02:00");
    var newDt = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dt, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("FLE Standard Time"));
    Console.WriteLine(newDt.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"));
```

By the way, `UTC+02:00` it's not name of timezone, real time will depend on country and daylight saving rules.

Answer (score 3):

Try this way

```
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(DateTime.Now, "New Zealand Standard Time", "UTC")
```

More  discussions :

[How to convert DateTime in Specific timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869051/how-to-convert-datetime-in-specific-timezone)

http://blog.mozilla.org/it/2012/11/16/converting-timezone-specific-times-in-mysql/