# what languages can be used to add custom code inside a sql server report?

Tags: java, sql-server, reporting-services

I have some sql server reports - .rdl files in which I want to add custom code to do some time zone conversions. After some googling, I found that I can write custom code in Visual Basic. Is there any other language that is supported to write custom code? like java?

I dont know VB to write the code in VB. Is java supported for custom code in the reports?

Comment: What sort of "custom" timezone logic are you adding here? May be able to simplified more.

Comment: Trying to convert datetime entry in a column to a specific timezone present in another column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your probleam is easy for solving without knowledge of VB.Net :), you can use this function for conversion (it will convert time without time zone (+00) to given timezone by id):

```
Shared Function ConvertServerTimeNow(ByVal systemDate As Date, ByVal timeZoneId As String, Optional ByVal daylightSavingsTime As Boolean = False) As Date
        Dim timeZoneInfo As TimeZoneInfo
        If timeZoneId Is Nothing Then
            Return systemDate
        Else
            timeZoneInfo = timeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneId)
            If daylightSavingsTime = False Then
                timeZoneInfo = timeZoneInfo.CreateCustomTimeZone(timeZoneInfo.Id, timeZoneInfo.BaseUtcOffset, timeZoneInfo.DisplayName, timeZoneInfo.StandardName, timeZoneInfo.DaylightName, Nothing, True)
            End If
        End If
        Return (timeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(systemDate, timeZoneInfo))
End Function
```

About TimeZoneID list you can refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7908482/1048105

About other languages:
You can use any language from .NET platform by adding custom assembly, but you can't write code exactly in rdl in other language then VB.NET. About custom assemblies you can read here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/920769, but it's hard to deploy it and I don't recommend to do this without need.