# How to convert WET/WEST Time to UTC?

Tags: c#

On an application I am saving all dates into a database as UTC.

However, the users insert the dates in Lisbon timezone ...

I checked and Lisbon timezone is WEST in summer and WET the rest of the year.

```
WET = Western European Time
WEST = Western European Summer Time
```

I then tried the following:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime nowUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;

DateTime.SpecifyKind(now, DateTimeKind.Local);

DateTime testNowUtc = now.ToUniversalTime();
```

But testNowUtc becomes the same as now and not as nowUtc

How can I solve this?

** UPDATE **

I tried the following:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime nowUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;

String zone = TimeZoneInfo.Local.IsDaylightSavingTime(now) ? TimeZoneInfo.Local.DaylightName : TimeZoneInfo.Local.StandardName;

DateTime testNowUtc = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(now, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(zone));
```

But when I run it I get the error:

```
The time zone ID 'GMT Daylight Time' was not found on the local computer.
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908343/list-of-timezone-ids-for-use-with-findtimezonebyid-in-c http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.findsystemtimezonebyid(v=vs.110).aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.converttimetoutc(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I added an update with code based on your suggestions but I get an error saying: "The time zone ID 'GMT Daylight Time' was not found on the local computer."

Comment: The timezone name is "GMT Standard Time".  Whether daylight savings are in effect only depends on the date.  Abbreviations like "WET" are arbitrary and ambiguous, lots of "CST" around.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime nowUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;

DateTime testNowUtc = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(now, TimeZoneInfo.Local);
```

The point of TimeZoneInfo is that it does daylight saving automatically.

Comment: Yes, I tried that but it does not give me the correct time. It gives me a one hour difference ... I think it is because of summer time ...

Comment: No. It should give you the correct answer. However, your original question was on West European time, whilst your computer is set to GMT. You aren't giving me the right information.