# vb.net timer tick for the time of other contry

Tags: vb.net

I making a form which should show dynamic time of london. But I am only able to show the time of my current contry please help.

Code is :

```
Public Class Frm_2

Private Sub Frm_2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Timer1.Enabled = True
    Label1.Left = Me.Width - Label1.Width - 50
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    Label1.Text = DateAndTime.TimeOfDay
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.converttime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
Label1.Text = DateAndTime.TimeOfDay
```

to

```
Label1.Text = System.TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(Now, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time")).ToString
```

Take a look at [List of Timezone ID's for use with FindTimeZoneById() in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908343/list-of-timezone-ids-for-use-with-findtimezonebyid-in-c) for the list of various timezeones