# IANA/Olson timezone support in C#

Tags: c#, timezone

C# supports different timezone id's across the globe. Please find list of time zones that are being supported by C# in below link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg154758.aspx

The timezone id's are used in C# library functions to convert times across the timezones.

[e.g. `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId("Hawaiian Standard Time")`]

Similarly I want support for AMERICA/MIQUELON, which is not present in the msdn list provided in above link.

Can somebody please provide workaround for this specific timezone?

Comment: You can **easily** enumerate all timezones known to C# / .NET by looking at the [code presented in this other SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908343/list-of-timezone-ids-for-use-with-findtimezonebyid-in-c) - if your timezone strings show up - they're supported by .NET ...

Comment: It is not part of Canada, it covers two small islands that are part of France, just 6000 people live there.  Web sites disagree but the majority favor UTC-3:00 with daylight savings.  Too obscure to be covered by the built-in Windows timezones, non-zero odds that they follow Newfoundland.  Best thing to do is ask your customer what they do about it.

Comment: Why don't you just use another timezone that uses the same UTC offset?

Answer (score 3):

Time zone identifiers like `"America/Miquelon"` and the others you listed (before editing your question) are from the IANA time zone database.  You can read more in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) and [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database).

Note that they are usually presented in mixed case form, rather than in all capital letters.

The easiest and best way to work with these in .NET is via the [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/) library.

For example:

```
DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["America/Miquelon"];
Instant now = SystemClock.Instance.Now;
ZonedDateTime converted = now.InZone(tz);
```