# How Can I get Today's date with UFTC stamp in c#?

Tags: c#, datetime, formatting

Is there an inbuild DateTime functionality that could give me a string format of today's date as `2020-12-22T13:36:45 Etc/UTC (+00)`

I can think of these ways:

```
var date = DateTime.Now;
var result = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss") + " Etc/UTC (+00)";

Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss Etc/UTC (+00)"));            
//Gives '2020-12-23T10:59:59 EAc/UTC (+00)' - incorrect t replaced by A

Console.WriteLine(result);
//Gives '2020-12-23T10:59:59 Etc/UTC (+00)' Correct,
```

As you can see I can get the correct format, though I am not sure this is the best solution, as it looks very artificial.

Is there a better way to format the string?

Comment: No, I don't believe there is. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30864731/iana-olson-timezone-support-in-c-sharp

Comment: If the result is supposed to be in UTC, you should be using `DateTime.UtcNow`, not `DateTime.Now`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about `date.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss 'Etc/UTC (+00)'")`

or if you need the real timezone, `date.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss 'Etc/UTC ('zzz')'")`