# How to convert Dynamics AX Timezone to C# TimeZoneInfo?

Tags: c#, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I need to convert a [Timezone](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg848856.aspx) on Dynamics AX 2012 R3 to a `TimeZoneInfo` on C#.
I'm doing this on my C# code. I get an int from Dynamics ([Timezone](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg848856.aspx) enum).

I get the [Timezone](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg848856.aspx) enum from table `LogisticsPostalAddress`.

Are there any methods to convert it? I couldn't find much information on that and I'd really like to avoid creating a code that would do a from X to Y for every single possibility. Would I be able to use that Value provided at the referenced link? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not sound cool, but I think you will have to provide the mapping table yourself between the [Timezone System Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg848856.aspx) and the name valid to 
[Instantiate a TimeZoneInfo Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397765(v=vs.110).aspx).

The [list of names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7908482/4509) should be quite static, but remember to catch `TimeZoneNotFoundException` and `InvalidTimeZoneException` when using [FindSystemTimeZoneById](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.findsystemtimezonebyid(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Actually, it's the only option. The Dynamics Timezone values are completely arbitrary

Comment: Well, thank you for the answer... since I did my research before asking I was prepared for that =/ well, monkey job ahead... Thanks

Comment: I recently stumbled upon this as well and just started a git repo https://github.com/joacar/MicrosoftDynamics. Less developers doing monkey job is more happier developers :)