# Need a User Friendly List of Timezones (GetSystemTimeZones)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I'm building a .NET Core application and need to add a calendar to the app which led me to googling how to handle timezones so I can build a dropdown on the front-end. NET has a function (TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones) that has a verbose list of timezones (400-something) and I was wondering if someone has a more condensed list that is logically grouped similar to how the Windows OS displays it?

As you can see below for instance Eastern Time condenses US & Canada but still leaves exceptions for Indiana.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: This might help: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/21409/how-to-make-selecting-a-timezone-more-user-friendly

Comment: this might be of interest to you https://www.joeaudette.com/blog/2016/06/23/cross-platform-timezone-handling-for-aspnet-core

Comment: Have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908343/list-of-timezone-ids-for-use-with-findtimezonebyid-in-c

Comment: I'll check these out guys and see if it points me in the right direction