# Given DateTime In CEST (Germany), Need To Know EST Time (Including DST)

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

I'm writing a C# Windows service that opens a text file that has a date and time column.  Both of these are in CEST time in Germany.  I need to know what these times are in EST.  I don't know how to factor in the daylight savings time on both sides as well.  Can someone please guide me with this?  I have no idea how.

```
lsRetrievedDateTime = cellvalues[10] + " " + cellvalues[11];
ldRetrievedDateTimeCEST = DateTime.ParseExact(MyDateString, "M/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss", null);

//  ldRetrievedDateTimeCEST is actually Germany time and we need to convert it to EST.
```

Comment: [Took me 2 seconds to google](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/converting-between-time-zones)

Comment: Be aware, `DateTime` itself doesn't keep time zone information. If you _really_ wanna deal with time zones, I suggest you to use [NodaTime](https://nodatime.org/) instead.

Comment: @TJWolschon, this includes DST adjustments as well?  How do I start with CEST and not UTC to convert to EST?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TimeZoneInfo` and `DateTimeOffset`

```
lsRetrievedDateTime = cellvalues[10] + " " + cellvalues[11];
ldRetrievedDateTimeCEST = DateTime.ParseExact(MyDateString, "M/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss", null)    
//Create a TimeZoneInfo Object and set TimeZone
var info = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
//Create DateTimeOffSet object with TimeZoneInfo and DateTime as parameters.

DateTimeOffset est_time = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(ldRetrievedDateTimeCEST , info);

//Now you can use est_time

MessageBox.Show(est_time.ToString()); //will return EST time.
```

For diferent TimeZones you can check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908343/list-of-timezone-ids-for-use-with-findtimezonebyid-in-c)

Good Luck.