# Formatting UTC timestamp in local timezone

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, utc

I have a UTC timestamp created with the DateTime class.

`var time = DateTime.UtcNow;`

When I format it I get the following result:

```
time.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz")
> 2019-02-03T10:08:40+00:00
```

Which is correct but I want it to be formatted in the local timezone like this:

`2019-02-03T11:08:40+01:00` < note the +01:00

How can I get this?

I could use DateTime.Local in this example but the timestamp is actually coming from another system/module and so the solution has to work on something like DateTime.UtcNow

Comment: From [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#the-zzz-custom-format-specifier): "With `DateTime` values, the `"zzz"` custom format specifier represents the signed offset of the **local operating system's time zone** from UTC, measured in hours and minutes. It does not reflect the value of an instance's `DateTime.Kind` property". I think your local timezone on the server you are executing that code is _already_ UTC+0. I would suggest to check it one more time.

Comment: I get these results on my own PC and I'm 100% sure that time is in +1.

Comment: As long as the other system is generating the time with a timezone it doesn't matter if it is UTC or any other timezone.  Any DateTime is stored in Net as a UTC time.  Net will automatically convert the the datetime to correct value when you use PARSE.   Using UtcNow will give you issues because it will store the time incorrectly.  What you really want is something like this :             DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine(date.ToUniversalTime());

Comment: With `DateTime` values, you should be using `K`, not `zzz`.  Use `zzz` with `DateTimeOffset` values.  And if you want local, then use `DateTime.Now`, or `.ToLocalTime()` first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in converting a UTC DateTime into a specific timezone's local time you can take a look at the TimeZoneInfo class.
Here is an example:

```
var utcDate = DateTime.UtcNow;

// 04/02/2019 11:23:39
// Kind is Utc

var localDate = utcDate.ToLocalTime();

// 04/02/2019 12:23:39
// Kind is now local

var timeZoneId = "US Eastern Standard Time";

var timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneId);

DateTime usEasternStandardDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcDate, timeZone);

// 04/02/2019 06:23:39
// Kind is unspecified
```

Also you can take a look at
    [Convert UTC/GMT time to local time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179940/convert-utc-gmt-time-to-local-time) for more details and [List of Timezone ID's for use with FindTimeZoneById() in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908343/list-of-timezone-ids-for-use-with-findtimezonebyid-in-c) for a complete list of supported timezones

Answer (score 2):

I've done a little testing but I believe you will need to use DateTime.Now as opposed to DateTime.UtcNow.

When you use the 'z' characters in the format the conversion takes into account that you want a time offset and changes the time accordingly.

Give the following a try and let me know if it works for you:

`DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:MM:sszzzz")`

This gives me `2019-02-04T10:02:32+00:00` (I am in a UTC Time Zone though)

Comment: If your wanting to adjust the timezone deliberately to "+1" you can always use a [DateTimeOffset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/converting-between-time-zones)

Answer (score 1):

DateTime.UtcNow gives current time at UTC where time offset zone is 0. Change to DateTime.Now to get local time instead.

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss K")
// 2019-02-04T08:36:11 -02:00

DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss K")
// 2019-02-04T10:36:22 Z
```

Comment: Sorry but that's irrelevant. The `K` and `zzz` are different things.

Comment: @SonerGönül "K" will return time zone information, that's the question: "I want it to be formatted in the local timezone"

Comment: But OP wants to get UTC Offset part, `K` will return `Z` for `DateTimeKind.UTC` values as you can see in your second code part. This is definitely not what OP wants.