# Missing 'Mountain Standard Time' timezone when using FindTimeZoneById() c# on mac

Tags: c#, macos, timezone

I'm running an Azure Functions project locally on Mac OS. My issue is using the `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(String)` Method.

On input of 'Mountain Standard Time', which is included on Windows Platforms according to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908343/list-of-timezone-ids-for-use-with-findtimezonebyid-in-c). This is fine when pushed to the hosting platform which is Windows, but on my local machine an error is thrown.

How do I handle this locally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IDs and data used with `TimeZoneInfo` are platform dependent:

- On Windows, the IDs are the Microsoft time zone identifiers, as used with the `tzutil.exe` command, Win32 APIs, and are sourced from the Registry.

  - Example: `"Mountain Standard Time"`
- On Mac OSX, Linux, and other non-Windows platforms, the IDs are IANA time zone identifiers, as used by the `TZ` environment variable, `timedatectl`, `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`, `sudo systemsetup -settimezone timezone`, and other platform-specific utilities.  The data is sourced from the [IANA tz database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones).

  - Example: `"America/Denver"`

Thus you can change your code to the following, which will run on Linux and Mac OSX.

```
TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("America/Denver");
```

If you cannot change the identifiers used in your application, or are designing your application to be cross-platform and need to work with both sets of identifiers, then use my [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter) library:

```
// Either of these will work on any platform
TimeZoneInfo tzi = TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo("Mountain Standard Time");
TimeZoneInfo tzi = TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo("America/Denver");
```

See also the "Time Zone Databases" section of [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the detailed answer! I'll look into using your TimeZoneConverter library.

Comment: Cool.  Alternatively, you could switch to `America/Denver` and switch your Azure Functions app to be hosted on Linux instead of Windows.