# Timezone conversion mysql funtion to c#

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime, timezone, zoneinfo

How to convert convert_tz() in mysql to a c# function

Comment: MySQL uses this thing called the tz or [zoneinfo database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database). I chose as the duplicate question because it shows ways to implement that same database in C# / dotnet.

Answer (score 0):

**edit:**

Use TimeZoneInfo and choose zone by it's id ([here's why and how to check them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908343/list-of-timezone-ids-for-use-with-findtimezonebyid-in-c))

> IMPORTANT - This data is not static. New time zones are introduced into Windows as the governments of the world make changes. This is ultimately why there are not authoritative pages listing them in the docs. Do not rely on any hardcoded list, but call TimeZoneInfo.FindTimeZoneById() yourself, or use TZUTIL.EXE /L to list them. The answers below are only but a snapshot of the data at the time they were reported. DO NOT COPY FROM HERE TO HARDCODE INTO YOUR APPLICATION!

Example of code:

```
var exampleTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Now,DateTimeKind.Unspecified);

DateTime result = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(exampleTime,
TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Europe/London"),
TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("America/Denver"));
```

---

**Before changes in question:**

There's not such an overload for this method with such parameters.

[TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime overloads - documentation screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwdSh.png)

Source: [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo?view=net-5.0)

Comment: I know but I am trying to find something that can do what I was looking for.
I am relatively new to c# libraries and there are so many different timezone functionalities that i'm a bit lost

Comment: @Andy I edited my post, check this out. I hope it helps, gl!

Answer (score 0):

There are probably cleaner methods, but I keep a helper function that uses TimeZoneInfo(search the MS documentation to find the particular ID you need) in a custom TimeUtils class

```
public static DateTime ConvertToMST(DateTime dt)
{
    DateTime utc = dt.ToUniversalTime();
    return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utc, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Mountain Standard Time"));
}
```